# Accidentally changing names of the project

Tags: windows-phone-7, error-handling, nullreferenceexception, windows-phone-7.1

So I am writing an app for Windows Phone 7.
Today, I didn't know what got into me, but I naively thought that by changing the Assembly Name, the Xap File name, the deployment Title, and the regular Title I would change my application name. I keep getting a NullReferenceException and I think my program will never work again. I was really stupid in changing the names and I'm wondering if there's anyway to fix this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Apart from checking for any errors in the `WMAppManifest.xml` file - you also need to update the  startup object in your main phone application project if you've renamed it or its namespace.

To do this, right-click on your main project in Visual Studio and select Properties. In the "Application" tab, update the "Startup object" drop down to point to your new object, in the correct namespace. You probably want to check everything else on this setttings page is correct too.

[image: settings page screenshot]

Comment: this is Joseph!
So I clicked the "Startup Project" part, but the only things that scrolled down were my original startup project and (no set).
I also checked my WMAppManifest.xml and I can't seem to find an error. Can you help me?

Comment: I think this is due to the change in Assembly name from a quick test I did. Make sure that you do a full clean of the Visual Studio solution (or delete your bin\Debug and bin\Release directories which is pretty much the same thing).

Comment: So I tried deleting the bin/Debug(but I can't seem to find the bin/Release directory). However, the scrolldown from the "Startup Project" is still (no set) and my original project. I can't seem to find the file MainApp.App anywhere in my Project file. The error I still keep getting is the NullReferenceException and my application stops at the clock screen, the screen that shows immediately before going into the application itself. While debugging, it also mentions something about user idle. Mean anything? Thanks @Paul Annetts :)

Comment: If in doubt just create a new project with the correct name and copy across the code files from your busted one. It's not worth wasting too much of your time on figuring out why it's broken...

Comment: Had the same problem, Did a clean solution and it worked fine afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, solution:
1. change the namespace of 'App.xaml' & 'App.xaml.cs' to the target startup object name
2. clean and rebuild the solution
4. open the property window and choose the new 'startup object'